# General solution of $ab = cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $(a,b) =1, (c,d) =1, \text{ & } \exists m,n,o,p, \text{ s.t. } m,n,o,p,$ are relatively prime in pairs, then the most general solution of $ab = cd$ in integers is given by $a = mn, b=op, c = mo, d = np$.

*Note:* This question is repeated verbatim from the book of Uspensky, Heaslet, titled Elementary Number Theory.

It is obvious that there are at least $4$ (and maximum 6) co-prime pairs if there is equation: $ax + by = \pm 1, \text{ & } (a,b) =1$. The maximum number of co-prime pairs can be :

$$
\begin{align}
& \ (a,b) = 1  \text{, given }\\
& \ (a,x) = 1 \text{, if more than 4 co-prime pairs }\\
& \ (a,y) = 1 \\
& \ (b,y) = 1 \text{, if more than 4 co-prime pairs }\\
& \ (b,x) = 1 \\
& \ (x,y) = 1
\end{align}
$$

Approaching the problem, I am unable to make sense of the word "most general solution", as for me the general solution implies that straight-away  $gcd(a,b)≠1$ $≠gcd(c,d)$, e.g. $(a,b)=(8,8)$, $(c,d)=(3,21)$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there exists $n∈Z$ such that $gcd(a,b+nc)=1=gcd(c,d+na)=±1$. And with $b_1=b+nc$ and $d_1=d+na$ we have $ab_1−cd_1=ab−cd$.

Comment: The question is unclear. The part "$\text{ if } \exists m,n,o,p, \text{ s.t. } (m,n,o,p) =1$ is always satisfied, say for $m=n=o=p=1$. This does not imply that the most general solution of $ab=cd$ is given by $a=mo=b=op=c=mo=d=np=1$.

Comment: Please see my edit in OP.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  I have copied now exactly, and still I hope that there would be no difference, if I mentioned that $(m,n,o,p) =1$ instead of that they are relatively prime in pairs.

Comment: Down voting should be along with reason, never without that. Else, one gains little in pondering over the reason, the effort required increases, and still may be unclear. It is not bad, but reason should be a must. After all, it is a site for constructive improvement.

Comment: Dear Jiten, I just cannot understand the claim there, I am sorry. Take $m=n=o=p=1$. They are relatively prime in pairs. So then the claims says: "If $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$, and if there exist relatively prime $m=n=o=p=1$, then the most general solution to $ab=cd$ is $a=b=c=d=1$." No, this is not true. Take $a=1,b=5$ and $c=5,d=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, in case of interest, $z_1 z_4 - z_2 z_3$ is the normal form suggested for a quaternary quadratic form of signature $++--.$ Fricke and Klein (1897), page 503 https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false  I have a paperback reprint of the original, the A.M.S. is coming out with an English translation this month. So, there is  reason to want the  integral null vectors for this form, for the automorphism group.

Comment: @WillJagy Oh yes, this is nice, and I have seen it. But here I am fighting with quantifiers somehow.

Comment: @WillJagy I hope the OP is the same, except for a different way of stating the same fact.

Comment: I have stated after the highlighted text, my approach. It was no-where specified in this form in the book, and I feel it is okay, but incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, with no quantifiers at all. With $ab=cd,$ take $g = \gcd(a,c).$ Let
$a = g \alpha$ and $c = g \gamma,$ so that $\gcd(\alpha, \gamma) = 1.$ We have
$$ g \alpha b = g \gamma d, $$
$$  \alpha b = \gamma d.  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**LEMMA:** If $r|st$ and $\gcd(r,s) = 1,$ then $r|t.$ **PROOF:** [We have some integers $x,y$ with $rx+sy=1.$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) We have some integer $u$ such that $ru=st.$ Then
$$ ruy = syt = (1-rx) t = t - rxt,  $$
$$ ruy + rxt = t, $$
$$ r(uy+xt) = t,  $$
$$r |t  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Since $\gcd(\alpha, \gamma) = 1,$ we know $\alpha | d,$ and we name
$$ d = \alpha h. $$ Then $\alpha b = \gamma \alpha h$ gives
$$ b = \gamma h. $$
It follows that $\gcd(b,d) = h$ and
$$ \gcd(a,b,c,d) = \gcd(g,h).  $$
We get
$$ a = g \alpha, \; b = \gamma h, \; c = g \gamma, \; d = \alpha h.   $$
We find $ \gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$ if and only if we can additionally demand $\gcd(g,h)=1,  $ where we had already built in $\gcd(\alpha, \gamma) = 1.$

With the original letters, we have $ab=cd$ and $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$ if and only if there exist $m,n,o,p$ such that 
$$ \gcd(n,o) = 1 \; \; \mbox{AND} \; \; \; \gcd(m,p) = 1 $$ and
$$ a=mn, \; b = op, \; c = mo, \; d = np. $$

Here is an excerpt from Fricke and Klein (1897), where they discuss normal forms for (indefinite) quaternary quadratic forms of signatures $+++-$ and $++-- \; \; .$ At the top of page 503, for signature $++-- \; \; ,$ they recommend the normal for $z_1 z_4 - z_2 z_3,$ or $ab-cd$ in our letters.

[image]

Comment: But what makes sure that $\alpha \mid d$, I am not able to see that. Particularly, because it is very much equally possible that $b \mid d$. Or, is it that WLOG, you have assumed that $a,c$ have a common factor.

Comment: @jiten I inserted a lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a,b,c,d\;$are positive integers such that $ab = cd.\;$Then
$$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{d}{b} = \frac{m}{n}$$
for some relatively prime positive integers $m,n,$ uniquely determined.

Then 
$$\frac{a}{c} = \frac{m}{n} \implies a = ms,\;\;c= ns$$
for some positive integer $s$ (namely, $s=\gcd(a,c))$.

Similarly,
$$\frac{d}{b} = \frac{m}{n} \implies d = mt,\;\;b= nt$$
for some positive integer $t$ (namely, $t=\gcd(d,b)$).

But these conditions are also sufficient since
$$(ms)(nt) = (ns)(mt)$$
Thus, for positive integers $a,b,c,d\;$to satisfy $ab = cd,\;$a necessary and sufficient condition is
$$a = ms,\;\;c= ns,\;\;d=mt,\;\;b=nt$$
where $m,n,s,t\;$are positive integers, and $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Suppose we also have
\begin{cases}
\gcd(a,b) = 1\\[6pt]
\gcd(c,d) = 1\\
\end{cases}

We want to show $m,n,s,t$ are relatively prime in pairs.

We already have $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

For the remaining pairs,
\begin{align*}
&\gcd(c,d)=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\gcd(ns,mt)=1\\[4pt] 
\implies\;&
\begin{cases}
\gcd(m,s)=1\\[4pt]
\gcd(n,t)=1\\[4pt]
\gcd(s,t)=1\\[4pt]
\end{cases}\\[10pt]
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{and also}\\[10pt]
&\gcd(a,b)=1\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\gcd(ms,nt)=1\\[4pt] 
\implies\;&
\begin{cases}
\gcd(m,t)=1\\[4pt]
\gcd(n,s)=1\\[4pt]
\end{cases}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: So, what the significance of the words " the most general solution". I am unclear on that part.

Comment: It means a necessary and sufficient condition, expressed in terms of equations.

Comment: Thanks, but does not my solution also point to the same thing.

Comment: The idea is to express the conditions in the form
$$a =\; ...,\;\;b = \;...,\;\;c =\;...,\;\;d=\;...$$

Comment: So, it means that I lacked the needed steps, and went on to a different direction.

Comment: So those first lines were yours, not the authors? If so, your claim looks OK, but needs an argument to support it.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand. There was a two-line question as in the highlighted text, rest all is mine.

Comment: Ok, so if the specified conditions were the author's, then I don't see that you proved it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to find all the solution to $ab=cd$.

Let $m = gcd(a,c)$, then $a=mx$ and $c=my$ where $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime. So we have $$ bmx = dmy\Longrightarrow bx = dy\Longrightarrow x|dy \Longrightarrow x|d$$
Last implication is true due to Euclid lemma. So we have $d=xn$ for some $n $ and now $bx =xny$ so $b=ny$.

So $a=mx$, $b=ny$, $c=my$ and $d=nx$, where $x,y$ are relatively prime, and since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, $m$ and $n$ must be also relatively prime.

Comment: Can you explain what the role of $m,n,o,p$ in the question is?

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde Do you agree ?

Comment: Your answer looks fine. But was it the question?

Comment: But it is in the title of the post.

Comment: In the title, yes, but in the text?

Comment: I agree, and and I should be sorry answering un intelligible question, not you